# Shared service provider NServiceBus and ASPNET Core

Tags: nservicebus

I'm creating a way to publish integration events via NServiceBus that are published from within an operation executed in a handler. The path I've chosen is bridge the `IIntegrationEventProvider` with `IEventCollectionPublisher` to get the published events from domain layer.

```cs
public sealed class Bridge : IIntegrationEventProvider /* Infrastructure */,
                             IEventCollectionPublisher /* Domain */
{
   private readonly List<object> _events = new List<object>();

   void IEventCollectionPublisher.Publish(object domainEvent) { _events.Add(domainEvent): }

   IReadOnlyCollection IIntegrationEventProvider.GetEvents() => _events;
}
```

Since NServiceBus has its own service provider (`IBuilder`) I need to resolve the class doing the application operation from the `IServiceProvider` that is made available to pipeline in `ServiceScopedBehavior`. Doing this I can get the bridge instance that contains the events published from domain layer and publish them as integration events using NServiceBus.

I published a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/joacar/273d84da5219bf57c8d47d1a59cff68f) with (hopefully) the code pieces needed to grasp what I'm trying to achieve.

The question is: can I instruct NServiceBus to just delegate calls to the application service provider instead of building it and copy all instructions in `endpoint.UserContainer<ServiceBuilder>()`? Below is an example

```cs
internal sealed class Handler : IHandleMessages<Command>
{      
    public async Task Handle(Command message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        // Resolved from ASPNET DI
        var useCase = context.GetService<CommandUseCase>();
        // _useCase is resolved NSB DI since injected from constructor
        Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(useCase, _useCase), "");
        await useCase.Execute().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

This way I could inject to correct scoped application class in the handler constructor instead of resolving it from the scope provided by `IServiceProvider` that is made available from `context.Extensions.Get<IServiceScope>().ServiceProvider`.

Thanks for help

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [ASP.NET Core integration sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/dependency-injection/aspnetcore/) could be useful. Starting from version 7.2 sharing of the DI infrastructure between ASP.NET and NServiceBus is much simpler. There is also a specialized [NServiceBus.Extensions.Hosting adapter package](https://discuss.particular.net/t/nservicebus-extensions-hosting-1-0-0-major-release-available/1481) that adds `UseNServiceBus` API.

Comment: That sample is what I was looking for. Looking forward to the release date, hopefully next week. Thanks

Comment: We've just released a helper package to simplify things further https://discuss.particular.net/t/nservicebus-extensions-hosting-1-0-0-major-release-available/1481